# Why html content inside BeginForm function isn't applied

Tags: css, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In mvc5 razor view, when I place the html content inside `BeginForm()`, the background is not applied but when I kept outside it works correctly

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
 <form class="form-signin mg-btm">
       <h3 class="heading-desc">Login</h3>
              <hr />
        <div class="main">  
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email,new {@class ="form-control" ,placeholder = "Email",rel="popover",data_original_title = "Enter your Email",autofocus = ""  } )                                   
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
      <br />
      @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password,new {@class ="form-control" ,placeholder = "Password",rel="popover",data_original_title = "Enter your Password" } )                                   
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
     <br />
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)   
         @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.RememberMe)                                
       <br />
      @Html.ValidationSummary()
   <span class="clearfix"></span>   
  </div>



  .form-signin {
   max-width: 400px; 
   display:block;
   background-color: #f7f7f7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #eaeaea;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #eaeaea;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #eaeaea;
   border-radius:2px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@using (Html.BeginForm()) itself a form elements, you don't have to explicitly create a form element. Hope this helps

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionName","YourControllerName",null,FormMethod.Post,
    new {@class="form-signin mg-btm" }))
     {

           <h3 class="heading-desc">Login</h3>
                  <hr />
            <div class="main">  
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email,new {@class ="form-control" ,placeholder = "Email",rel="popover",data_original_title = "Enter your Email",autofocus = ""  } )                                   
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
          <br />
          @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password,new {@class ="form-control" ,placeholder = "Password",rel="popover",data_original_title = "Enter your Password" } )                                   
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
         <br />
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)   
             @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.RememberMe)                                
           <br />
          @Html.ValidationSummary()
       <span class="clearfix"></span>   
      </div>
}
```

Comment: Super.Thanks for u r great support